# Python linebreak and indent with 1 line of code?

Tags: python, indentation, line-breaks

In Python, is it possible to print a string with a linebreak and indent, but only with 1 line of code? (see below)

```
    Wow!
        This is on a new line!
```

Comment: I strongly suggest reading up on Python strings: `print("Wow!\n\tThis is on a new line!")`

Comment: `print('\tWow!\n\tThis is on a new line!')`?

Comment: Make sure you do as @NiemaMoshiri, specifically lookup the term "escape characters".

Answer (score 1):

in python `\n` will produce a new line and `\t` will indent a line in(as the tab key on your keyboard would). so the following should work:

```
print('\tWow!\n\t\tThis is on a new line!')
```

do note how I unlike the comments below the question use `\t` twice on the second line to indent it further than the line above it